# Помогите с регулярными выражениями

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть некий текст, например, возьмем отрывок стихотворения А.С. Пушкина (немного его подредактировав):

```
Мороз и солнце; день чудесный №1 !
Еще ты дремлешь, №2 друг прелестный -
№3 Пора, красавица№4, проснись:
Открой №5 сомкнуты негой взоры
№6Навстречу северной Авроры,
Звездою севера явись!
```

Нужно заменить все **№N** на **номерN**, что бы получилось так:

```
Мороз и солнце; день чудесный номер1 !
Еще ты дремлешь, номер2 друг прелестный -
номер3 Пора, красавица№4, проснись:
Открой номер5 сомкнуты негой взоры
№6Навстречу северной Авроры,
Звездою севера явись!
```

Хотелось бы что бы все **№N(нету символов перед и после данной конструкции)** где **N- число** , заменялось на **номерN**

Comment: То, что 4 и 6 не заменились - это ошибка формулировки или ожидаемое поведение?

Comment: проще "№" заменить на "номер" :)

Comment: @gil9red, если в тексте может быть просто № без числа и его нужно оставить, то не проще.

Comment: То, что 4 и 6 не заменились - это ошибка формулировки или ожидаемое поведение?
ожидаемое поведение

Comment: проще "№" заменить на "номер" :) – gil9red

нет не проще, если будет выражение типо №два, оно не должно быть заменено, а будет

Comment: Я не понял, вам нужно заменять все последовательности из № и цифр, кроме №4 и №6?

Comment: прошу прощение , что наверное не очень правильно выражаю свои мысли.
мне нужно, что бы все №цифра заменялись , если перед ними ничего нету и после них ничего нету.

Comment: Сформулируйте в вопросе конкретные правила, которым должно соответствовать регулярное выражение, приведите примеры ожидаемого поведения. Сейчас неясно, чего вы хотите.

Comment: постарался дописать более понятно чего хочу

Comment: Вы бы ещё лестницы Маяковского предложили разобрать.

Answer (score 5):

Регулярка довольно простая: `№(\d+)`
Проверить в действии можно здесь: http://regexr.com/3dbt1

Answer (score 3):

ищем номера, перед которыми пробелы или начало строки и после которых цифры до конца слова

```
(?<=\s|^)(№)(?=\d+(?:\s|$))
```

[демо](https://www.regex101.com/r/zT8vY3/2)

Comment: Спасибо! То что надо!

Answer (score 1):

Я пробовал сделать вот так:`/\s№(\d+)\s/s/\s№\b/номер/g`
Но это не заменяет , если №N первая в строке.
И заменяет если после №N идут символы ( прим: `№6Навстречу`) а не должно, это конечно решается \s , но тогда теряются цифры , а надо что бы они не терялись.